# spring boot starter security not generating default password in logs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-starter-security

After running the spring boot application, the default password is not generating in logs.
Please find the following logs:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weczl.png)

2. POM.XML

   org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

The above details are for the dependencies added to pom XML. Does anybody have any idea why it is not generating a default password in logs?

Comment: To help debug, do you get the same output when running in the IDE and on the command line?

Comment: So far, I ran this only from ide.

Comment: Try running it from the command line as well. I also suggest running a `mvn clean` beforehand.

Comment: no, it din't work

Comment: Do you have any security configuration (something that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`)? Or do you have anything related to security set in `application.yml` or `application.properties`?

Comment: it worked, after removing the other imports like UserDetails , UserDetailsService related to spring security.

Answer (score 0):

So, the above query is resolved now.
Basically, I'd used the below functionality of spring security in my project, which wasn't allowing the default password to be generated:-

1. UserDetailsService
2. usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter

After removing these imports and the functionality associated with these, the default password is now generated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs3HJ.png)